# Evaluate comparison operator from table column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to expand a field value into a comparison operator? Something like this:

```
create table math (
    value1 int,
    value2 int,
    operator text
);
insert into math values(1,2,'>=');

select * from math where value1 operator value2;
```

PS: I know that it is possible to solve this use case by means of case when, but want to know if there is an alternative solution.

Comment: Since the values and operator are stored in the row, you'd solve this by also storing the result: `false`. Could you show a more practical example which is not deterministic?

Comment: Do you have a fixed/predetermined set of operators in mind? If you only want to deal with `>=`, `<=`, `=`, `>`, `<`, and `<>` then a CHECK constraint combined with a CASE expression would do the trick; ugly perhaps but not as ugly as dynamic SQL (i.e. SQL's version of `eval`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this only using `case` statement, or using `case` in the function code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_values(pvalue1 integer, pvalue2 integer, pop text)
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    v_count integer;
    v_ret bool; 
begin

    case pop
       when '=' then
          return (pvalue1 = pvalue2);
       when '>' then
          return (pvalue1 > pvalue2);
       when '<' then
          return (pvalue1 < pvalue2);
       when '>=' then
          return (pvalue1 >= pvalue2);
       when '<=' then
          return (pvalue1 <= pvalue2);
       else
          return false;
       end case;
          
END;
$function$
;
```

Then you can use this function on your query:

```
select * 
    from examples.math 
where 
    examples.check_values(value1, value2, "operator");
```

I think that this is only possible using the `case` operator